# Model depends on a source named '<source_name>' which was not found - dbt

Tags: dbt

I'm trying use source() func in dbt and when I keep getting the following error.

> Model 'model.demo_dbt.snowflake_sample_data_store'
> (models\store_analysis\snowflake_sample_data_store.sql) depends on a
> source named 'SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.STORE' which was not found

model : snowflake_sample_data_store.sql

```
with store_sales as (
    select * from {{ source('snowflake_sample_data','store') }}
),
final as (
    select * from store_sales
)
select * from final
```

Source: source.yml

```
version: 2

sources:
  - name: snowflake_sample_data
    description: "Snowflake's sample data for testing"
    database: snowflake_sample_data
    schema: TPCDS_SF10TCL
    tables:
      - name: store
        description: contains clients store information
```

dbt_project.yml

```
name: 'demo_dbt'
version: '1.0.0'
config-version: 2

profile: 'demo_dbt'

model-paths: ["models"]
analysis-paths: ["analyses"]
test-paths: ["tests"]
seed-paths: ["seeds"]
macro-paths: ["macros"]
snapshot-paths: ["snapshots"]

clean-targets:         # directories to be removed by `dbt clean`
  - "target"
  - "dbt_packages"


models:
  demo_dbt:
    # Config indicated by + and applies to all files under models/example/
    example:
      +materialized: view
```

I'm not able to figure out what is missing.

Note: my target schema in profile.yml is different ,I hope this should not impact.

Comment: where is your `source.yml` file? It needs to be in the `models` directory

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to Snowflake case sensitivity.

Your source database is defined as "snowflake_sample_data" however you can see from the error message that the query is actually referencing "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA" - these are different identifiers in Snowflake as it is case sensitive.

If the source database is literally "snowflake_sample_data" (lower case) then you will need to enable quoting for identifiers so that they are not automatically converted to upper case. See https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-properties/quoting

This also applies to table/view names in the source as well.